# Mongodb Search children and return children and parent

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb and try to query the children elements.
Suppose my collection is like this:

```
{
     name: "test1",
     children:[
         {
             name:"test2",
             children:[
                 {
                      name:"test3"
                 },
                 {
                      name:"test4"
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]

}
```

I want to find 'test4' and return record like this:

```
{
     name: "test1",
     children:[
         {
             name:"test2",
             children:[
                 {
                      name:"test4"
                 }
             ]
         }
     ]

}
```

I haved tried $elementMatch but it returns the whole reocrd including both 'test3' and 'test4'. How can I achieve this? Thanks so much for the help!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `positional projection operator $` for your purpose.

try this:

```
db.collection_name
  .find({'children.children.name' : givenName},{'children.children.$' : 1});
```

for more information on positional operator `$ (projection)`, go through [MongoDB $(projection) documentation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment! I tried this and still got both children elements and root elements disappeared@@

Answer (score 0):

I achieved this by this command:

```
db.product_profile_menu.aggregate([
{ $match: {
    children: {$elemMatch: {children: {$elemMatch: {name: "test4"}}}}
}},
{ $unwind: "$children"},
{ $unwind: "$children.children"},
{ $match: {"children.children.name":"test4"}}]).pretty()
```

I am not sure if it is the right way to do this so if someone find error in this, please feel free to add comment here.